# When we update the jdk, what action is needed for previously installed Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans6.7

When we update the jdk, what action is needed for previously installed Netbeans?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No action needed if you don't remove previous version, if this isn't the case and you want your NB to use new version of jdk then edit `netbeans.conf` 
update following property

```
netbeans_jdkhome=
```

Answer (score 0):

Tell Netbeans to use your newly installed JDK.